# Traveling with visa in my old passport

Tags: visas, passports, uae

My old passport in which an ECR was stamped,with passport expiry date in 2017.I got a Dubai visit visa on its passport number but later on as I was told that it'l be a problem for me to travel to Dubai so I got a new passport re-issued with ECNR with a new passport number.

So will it be a problem for me to travel or do I have to get my UAE visit visa details of my old passport number change to my new passport number?

Comment: @FK1 a title is important, imagine if all questions have bad title such as "please answer", then the questions page would literally hurt your eyes, it is like a reference textbook without index page.

Answer (score 2):

You can travel to UAE using the visa in the old passport, from [Emirates website](http://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/essential_information/visa_passport_information/find_visa_requirements/visa_passport_information_results.aspx?NC=IN&NV=India&DC=AE&DV=United+Arab+Emirates&h=5d9a5df925d0cb84fa52a2c3c20609127281eb6):

> Valid visas in expired passports are accepted provided accompanied by new passport.